# Comparison Test Proof (Hammack's Book of Proof, Third Edition, Exercise 13.8.2)

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am currently going through Hammack's *Book of Proof* (3rd edition), and have been stuck on the following exercise for the past two weeks.

> Prove the *comparison test*: Suppose $\Sigma a_k$ and $\Sigma b_k$ are series. If $0 \le a_k \le b_k$ for each $k$, and $\Sigma b_k$ converges, then $\Sigma a_k$ converges. Also, if $0 \le b_k \le a_k$ for each $k$, and $\Sigma b_k$ diverges, then $\Sigma a_k$ diverges.

Now, the reader is instructed to prove this using "Definition 13.7 (and Definition 13.5, as needed)" from the book which goes as follows.

> **Definition 13.7**
>
> A series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ **converges** to a real number $S$ if its sequence of partial sums $\{s_n\}$ converges to $S$. In this case we say $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k = S$.
>
> We say $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ **diverges** if the sequence $\{s_n\}$ diverges. In this case $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ does not make sense as a sum or does not sum to a finite number.

> **Definition 13.5**
>
> A sequence $\{a_n\}$ **converges** to a number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ provided that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N > \mathbb{N}$ for which $n > N$ implies $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$.
>
> If $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$, we denote this state of affair as $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$
>
> If $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to any number $L$, then we say it **diverges**.

I am currently focusing on the first statement. Also, that statement intuitively makes sense to me: if the series $\Sigma a_k$ has only non-negative terms, then it will either converge or diverge *to infinity*. However, since $0 \le a_k \le b_k$, it follows that $\Sigma a_k \le \Sigma b_k$ and thus, if $\Sigma a_k$ did diverge to infinity we would have a contradiction. I am able to formalize this as follows.

*Proof*. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $\Sigma a_k$ diverges to infinity. That is, for every $L \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a number $N' \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n \ge N'$ implies $A_n > L$ where $A_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum of $\Sigma a_k$. Also, because $\Sigma b_k$ converges to some number $B \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N'' \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n > N''$ implies $|B_n - B| < \epsilon$ where $B_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum of $\Sigma b_k$. Further, notice that if $0 \le a_k \le b_k$ for each $k$, then $A_n = (a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n) \le (b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n) = B_n$.

Now, take $\epsilon > 0$ and $L = B - \epsilon$. Also, let $N = \max(N', N'')$. Then, if $n > N$ we have $A_n > B - \epsilon$ and $|B_n - B| < \epsilon$, or $B_n < \epsilon + B$. Thus we have $B_n < \epsilon + B < A_n$ and $A_n \le B_n$, a contradiction. Therefore, $\Sigma a_k$ must converge.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

The problem I have is that although divergence to infinity implies divergence, divergence does not imply divergence to infinity. Therefore, for my proof to be complete, I would need to show that if $\Sigma a_k$ diverges then it must diverge to infinity. However, I am unable to formalize this idea. I have looked it up online and stumbled accross proofs that uses Cauchy sequences or the monotone convergence theorem, but nothing that uses only the definitions above. I also tried a direct proof without any luck.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\sum a_k$ does not converge, then $\sum a_k$ does not converge to $B$. The definition of divergence, then (any divergence, not just infinity) tells us that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $N>0$ there is an $n>N$ such that $|A_n-B|>\epsilon$. You can use that to prove your contradiction.

Comment: @c_gnar , so from $|A_n - B| > \epsilon$ you have that $A_n - B > \epsilon$ or $A_n - B < - \epsilon$ right? If so, the former leads to a contradiction since from $B_n - B < \epsilon$ it follows that $B_n - B < A_n - B$, and thus $B_n < A_n$, a contradiction. However, I fail to see how to get to a contradiction from the later.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. Try this: $A_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence. Therefore, if $A_n$ is bounded above, it must converge (least upper-bound principle). That should take care of the divergence $\Rightarrow\to\infty$ issue you raised.

Comment: @c_gnar, thanks for the precision. The problem I have however is that I have not been introduced to the idea of bounded series or least upper-bound principle and the book never mentions them. I believe the reader is expected to find a solution that does not reference does principles.

Comment: gotcha. They are defining divergence of a series as "doesn't make sense as a sum, or diverges to infinity." That first criterion is vague. You may need clarification on that term. My assumption would be that it means the sum makes sense iff $\sum_{k=1}^na_k\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $n$. In this case, if $\sum a_k$ "doesn't make sense as a sum", as they put it, you could prove that for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ $a_k\not\in\mathbb{R}$, in which case $a_k\leq b_k$ is not even relevant, so you can focus your case of divergence on divergence to infinity. Perhaps?

Comment: Well the definition of divergence reads "does not make sense as a sum or does not sum to a finite number". This is different than "sum to infinity". Take a series such as $\{0, 1, 0, 1, ...\}$. That series does not converge and does not diverge to infinity. So I don't think I can assume that the series either converges or diverges to infinity. However, since all terms in the series are positive, it feels like if it diverges it has to diverge to infinity. This is the missing piece I am unable to formalize.

Comment: Ok I see. Well, you can for sure start with the following: Letting $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$, $s_k\leq s_{k+1}$. That is easy to prove directly. This rules out oscillating sequences like the one you proposed. Truthfully, I don't know but I'm doubtful that it's possible to prove non-decreasing sequences converge or to go infinity without using the least upper-bound principle. It is a well-known theorem called the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: That's why I suggested more clarity on the book's definition of divergence. I was thinking perhaps they add some details that either state or imply divergence to infinity or nonsense sum.

Comment: Yes the more I read about this the more I think what you are saying is correct. I will start looking and reading about the monotone convergence theorem and will probably simply use it to complete my proof. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Sure thing! Yeah that's interesting. I just looked at the book you're using. Not something that looks like it would introduce the least upper-bound principle. Typically one learns about that in a real analysis class and spends time proving theorems that use it as support. It's also one of the first things you learn in real analysis. You may have just been given a problem that requires more than is offered for support. Just out of curiosity, what class is this? Undergrad/Grad?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121248/discussion-between-madibam-and-c-gnar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to complete my proof by showing that if $\Sigma a_k$ diverges, then it must diverge to infinity.

*Proof*. Suppose the series $\Sigma a_k$ diverges. Then, for all $L \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a number $n>N$ for which $|A_n - L| \ge \epsilon$ where $A_n$ is the $n$-th partial sum of $\Sigma a_k$. Also suppose that $a_k \ge 0$ for all $k$. We must show that this implies that $\Sigma a_k$ diverges to infinity, or, in other terms, that for all $L > 0$, there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n > N$ implies $A_n > L$.

Now, from $|A_n - L| \ge \epsilon$ we have $(A_n - L \ge \epsilon) \lor (A_n - L \le - \epsilon)$.

**Case 1.**
Suppose $A_n - L \ge \epsilon$. Thus, we have a number $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $n > N$ for which $A_n \ge L+ \epsilon$. However, from $a_k \ge 0$ we have that $A_{n+1} \ge A_n$ for all $n$. Therefore, $n' > n$ implies $A_{n'} \ge A_n \ge \epsilon + L$. That is, for all numbers $L+\epsilon = L' > 0$, we have a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n > N$ implies $A_n > L'$. That is, by definition, $\Sigma a_k$ diverges to infinity.

**Case 2.**
Suppose $A_n - L \le -\epsilon$. Now, from the definition of divergence, we also have a $N' > n$ for which there is a number $n' > N'$ such that $|A_{n'} - L| \ge \epsilon$, or $(A_{n'} - L \ge \epsilon) \lor (A_{n'} - L \le -\epsilon)$. From case 1 above we know that $A_{n'} - L \ge \epsilon$ implies convergence to infinity. Now, for $A_{n'} - L \le -\epsilon$, taking the difference of $A_{n'}$ and $A_n$ we get $A_{n'} - A_{n} \le 0$. That is, $(a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \dots + a_{n'}) \le 0$ and so it follow that $a_{n'} = 0$ for all $n' > N' > n$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $n' > n$ implies $|A_{n'} - A_n| = 0 < \epsilon$. Therefore, by definition, we have that $\Sigma a_k$ converges, a contradiction.

The above two cases show that if $\Sigma a_k$ diverges, then it must diverge to infinity. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$